# Unity выдает ошибку "name "NUnit" could not be found"

Tags: unity3d

Недавно появилась непредвиденная ошибка в движке Unity.[image: Вот консоль, при создании нового проекта выдаёт данную ошибку]

Если кто-то сталкивался с данной ошибкой, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: что-то не так ты удалил пхду

Comment: Вы новый участник, поэтому впредь советую, во-первых, обрезать скриншот до значимых вещей (нам не нужны твои часы, дата, пустой проект, и вотсап с вайбером), а, во-вторых, называть вопрос точнее. В будущем, если у кого-то возникнет похожая проблема (а она возникнет), он не сможет найти ваш вопрос и ответы по заголовку "ПРОБЛЕМА! ПОМОГИТЕ СРОЧНО!". Но сможет помочь, увидя "Ошибка такая-то, выдается так-то". Удачи.

Answer (score 0):

[Похожий вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884015/the-type-or-namespace-name-nunit-could-not-be-found)

> Правый клик на references в окне solution explorer или клик на "Add reference" (Добавить reference). Вам нужно будет загрузить nunit.framework.dll

> Вам нужно добавить reference NUNIT
>
> > Она называется nunit.framework.dl и ее можно скачать с сайта [NUNIT](https://nunit.org/)

Несколько ответов. Если хотите - можете посмотреть по ссылке оригинал

Comment: @ДмитрийВинокуров Если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, примите его, нажав галочку.